# Using Spotify API to get search result in the player

Tags: spotify

I know I can use the API command `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search` to get a search result in an JSON string.

But can I use a Spotify API command to send a search query to the player and **get the result in the player itself**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `spotify:search:<search_term>` works.

Try something like `spotify:search:the%20rolling%20stones` in a browser. It should link you to the app, in the search section. (Tested on macOS and iOS and it works)

Comment: Interesting. But in my cas, the browser (Chrome Windows) prompts me to open the app even if it is already open. I'd prefer a background solution using the API.

Comment: What I want is probably not feasible. I'll accept your answer that is close to what I was looking for. Thanks Alex.